# Sentry 2 Authentication workflow with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm building an authentication system using Sentry 2. The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to create a session for the user after he's authenticated and logged in via Sentry. This is my controller code:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    try 
    {
        $user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
        if ($user)
        {
            if(Input::get('remember')=='true')
                Sentry::loginAndRemember($user);     
        }
    }
    catch(\Exception $e)
    {
        return View::make('hello')->withErrors(array('login' => $e->getMessage()));
    }
    try
    {
        Sentry::login($user, false);
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\LoginRequiredException $e)
    {
        echo 'Login field is required.';
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotActivatedException $e)
    {
        echo 'User not activated.';
    }
    catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
    {
        echo 'User not found.';
    }
}
```

After I log in, to check if the user is actually logged in, I made another controller action which dumps the Authenticated user details:

```
public function index()
{
    var_dump(Auth::user());
}
```

var_dump() returns null. What am I missing here? I'm new to Laravel and Sentry. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to use `Sentry`, you no longer use Laravels `Auth`. They are completely independent of one another.

Instead, you now use

```
$user = Sentry::getUser();
```

See https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/users/find

Comment: Ohh, yes that worked. Didn't know both of them were independent! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

To access sentry session user use this 
 {{Sentry::getUser()}}

Auth::user() return laravel session object.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. Thanks! :)